# presenter notes for each incremental slide using xaringan in R

Tags: r, r-markdown, xaringan

Is it possible to add presenter notes to each incremental slide in Xaringan presentations? sometimes I need to have a particular note for the first bullet of my slide, but the presenter notes only appear until I have reached the last (or second to last) incremental slide.

Ideally, I would like to have something like this, but it does not work

```
---
# Heading

--

First idea

???
Notes about the first idea

--

Second idea

???
Notes about the second idea. 
---
```

Instead, I have to do something like this,

```
---
# heading

First idea 

--

Second idea

-- 

Third idea

???

Notes about first idea, 

Notes about the second idea

Notes about the third idea
---
```

I know that I could come up with a different way to make my slides so I am not contained by not having this option. However, It would be great if it could done. Does anyone know how to do it?

Thank you so much.

Comment: I wanted this feature in the past, too, but I'm afraid that it's not possible with xaringan or remark.js...